# SQL Writing Library

Tags: .net, sql, oop

Is anyone aware of a such a thing as a SQL writing library for .Net? I'm thinking it would be wrapper for generating queries in an object oriented style. Maybe something like the following:

```
class SelectQuery : BaseQuery
{
    List<Column> SelectedColumns { get; set; }
    Table MainTable { get; set; }
    List<Join> Joins { get; set; }
    List<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
    List<Column> Order { get; set; }

    string Write() { }
}
```

Nevermind why I'm looking for something to do this. And, there's no specific problem which this would address for me, I'm just interested in seeing such a thing.

Please note, I am not looking for an O/RM, but a means of writing SQL, and representing queries with objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started a project specifically for this. It's called [SeaQuail](http://seaquail.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

nHibernate has a new project underway called Antlr which is an Abstract Syntax Tree for SQL Queries. I've not looked at it but it might have you want.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL does this.
nHibernate does this.
LINQ to Entities does this.

Basically, you seem to be looking for an O/R mapper, of which there are a ton of competing products.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for an O/RM, but a means of writing SQL and representing it in objects. Likely, somewhere along the LINQs query processing pipeline there is just such a thing.

Comment: @sledgebox: Are you talking about the IQueryable<T> extension methods that LINQ maps to?

Answer (score 0):

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354999/visiomodeler-object-role-modeling-the-other-orm-who-uses-it) about Object Role Modeling. It's the only available tool I've ever seen for having a conceptual discussion about relational database design.